# Uncheck "Check All" checkbox when one of the checkbox is uncheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this mini project which is almost done. My problem is the checkall checkbox. It worked well checking all the checkboxes, but if I uncheck 1 checkbox from my tbody checkall checkbox still on a state of being checked.

below is my code.

to be pointed out well this is my checkall and uncheckall checkbox. which can also be found on snippet.

```
$('#checkAll').click(function(){
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('.cb').each(function(index){
    $(this).on("change", function(index) {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
            return;
        }
    });
})
```

```js
var tasks = [];
var count = 1000;

$('document').ready(function(){
 
 toggleRemoveAndMarkButtons();

 $('#add').click(function() {
  var desc  = $.trim($('#list-input').val());

  if (!desc) {
   item.id = "";
   alert("Input a description");
   return;
  }

  var status  = $('#task-status').val();
  item   = {};

  item.description = desc;
  item.status   = status;
  for(i = 0 ; i < tasks.length; i++)  {
   if(tasks[i].description.toUpperCase() == desc.toUpperCase()) {
    alert('Task description is already on the list. Please input new task description!')
    return;
   }
  }
  var id = count++;
  item.id = id;
  tasks.push(item);

  var row  = "'<tr id="+ item.id +" class='row'>'";
   row += "<td><input type='checkbox' class='cb' /></td>";
   row += "<td> #" + item.id + "</td>";
   row += "<td>" + item.description.toUpperCase() + "</td>";
   row += "'<td class="+ item.id +">" + item.status + "</td>";
   
  $("#mylist tbody").append(row);


  //clear input field
  $('#list-input').val('');
  $('#list-input').focus();
 });

 //remove list function
 $('#delete').on('click', function() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete selected task(s)?")){
         $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
          var rowId = $(':checkbox:checked').parents('tr').attr('id');
          var row   = $('tr#' + rowId);
          for(i=0; i < tasks.length; i++){
           if(tasks[i].id == rowId){
            tasks.splice(i, 1);
            break;
           }
          }
          row.remove();
         })
        }
        uncheckAfterActionClick();
        toggleRemoveAndMarkButtons();
    })

    $('#update').on('click', function() {
     if(confirm("Are you sure to Mark these as COMPLETE?")){
   var taskRow = $("#mylist tbody tr");

   $.each(taskRow, function(i, row) {
       if( $(this).find('td').eq(0).find("input").is(":checked") ) {
           $(this).find('td').eq(3).text("Complete");
           tasks[i].status = "Complete";
           $(this).addClass('complete');             
       }
   });
   $('tr')
     }
     uncheckAfterActionClick();
        toggleRemoveAndMarkButtons();
    })

    //check all
    $('#checkAll').click(function(){
     $(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
 });

 $('.cb').each(function(index){
  $(this).on("change", function(index) {
      if (!this.checked) {
          $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
          return;
      }
  });
 })

})


function toggleRemoveAndMarkButtons() {
 var howManyChecked = $('.cb:checked, .checkAll:checked').length;
 var disableButtons = howManyChecked == 0;
 $('#delete, #update').prop('disabled', disableButtons);
}

function uncheckAfterActionClick() {
 $('.cb, #checkAll').prop('checked', false);
    toggleRemoveAndMarkButtons();
}

//container style
$('.container').css({
 "width":"640px",
 "margin":"0 auto", 
 "text-align":"center"
});

$('#list-input').attr({'placeholder':"Input task description"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input id="list-input" />
  <input id="task-status" value="New" type="hidden"/>
  <button id="add">Add To List</button>
  <button id="delete" class="delete" disabled>Remove From List</button>
  <button id="update" disabled>Mark as Complete</button>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Your Task</h1>
  
  <div>
   <table id="mylist">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onchange="toggleRemoveAndMarkButtons()"/></th>
      <th>Task Number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Status</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo in your jQuery:

```
$('this').on("change", function(index) {
```

You're searching for `'this'` as a string in your selector, rather than using jQuery's contextual `$(this)`.

And this line won't work:

```
if (!this.checked) {
```

Instead, use the `.not()` selector:

```
if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
```

And lastly, your code to set the `change` events for each checkbox is only running on document ready - so it's trying to bind to `.cb` elements before they exist. Here's a fix for that:

Change this:

```
$('.cb').each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("change", function(index) {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
            return;
        }
    });
})
```

To this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.cb', function() {
  if ($(this).not(':checked')) {
    $("#checkAll").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Jorge Made another edit after looking over your code more.

Comment: @Jorge Found the final issue and verified a fix for it. Check it out, edited my answer one last time.

Comment: @JonUleis thanks. I also figured it that it has to be outside the document ready. But haven't tried (document).on(change ...

Comment: @Jorge You don't have to move that code - it'll work in the same place (if that's what you meant).

Answer (score 2):

I do something like this with the `length`:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".checkAll").click(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
  $("input:checkbox:not(.checkAll)").click(function () {
    $(".checkAll").prop("checked", $("input:checkbox:not(.checkAll):checked").length == 5);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" /> Check All</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Check 1</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Check 2</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Check 3</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Check 4</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Check 5</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks to this. gives me also an idea on how to do it differently